# Need to match multiple substrings in a string with a single regex pattern

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have 2 strings:

```
string1 = 'this is a beautiful string'
string2 = 'this is not a beautiful string'
```

i'm trying to find a Regex pattern that splits the two strings as follow:

```
string1 -> ['this is a', 'string']
string2 -> ['this is a', 'string']
```

the Regex pattern i'm trying to find GROUPS words next to each Others

the closest thing i was able to make is:

```
pattern = r'(this)? \s* (is)? \s* (\ba)? \s* (string)?'
```

which returns:

```
['this is a ', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ' string', '']
```

Comment: `?:` declares a [non-capturing group](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups).

Comment: i know, what's the point of your statement?


Edit: i'm sorry, i didn't put all the code therefore in this case ?: is useless,

It's now fixed

Comment: I know this changes your regex quite a lot, but how about this? `(?:\b(?:this|is|a|string)\s*)+`

Comment: I love you, thank you, far better than my regex pattern.
the only problem is that i get trailing spaces between words -> ['this is a ', 'string'] but i can remove them in python

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regex, is that everything is optional.  A side effect of this is you get zero-width matches between each character outside of your other matches.

```
(?:\b(?:this|is|a|string)\s*)+(?<!\s)
```

To address your question in the comments, the last part is a negative lookbehind to make sure the capture doesn't end with a space.